# django admin model syncdb not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The following Python code produces an error:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=False,default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,default="")
    content = models.TextField(blank=False,default="")
    #   status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,default="draft")
    published = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self):
        if self.date_created == None:
            self.date_created = datetime.now()
            self.date_modified = datetime.now()
            super(Post, self).save()
```

This is the error message I get.

```
 raise DeserializationError(e)
```

What I've tried:

on suncdb it raises error

My question:

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the published field after running syncdb?

Comment: calling super.save() should not be intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error once with my application, though with a minor change: syncdb didn’t throw any errors. But when I tried to access the model, I got that error. Anyway, what fixed it for me was:

```
python manage.py reset [appname]
python manage.py syncdb
```

Hopefully it can help you too. If you have any data, you should export it as a JSON, so you don't lose it with the reset.

Make a fixture (json) with the following command:

```
mkdir APPName/fixtures
python manage.py dumpdata APPName --format=json > APPName/fixtures/OriginalData.json
```

Reload the data with `syncdb`

You can read more about it here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures

Comment: yea it did help but now i am getting problems with the fixtures